# Does gcc -Ofast enable vectorization?

Tags: gcc, optimization, vectorization, auto-vectorization, fast-math

I am currently compiling spec2000 art benchmark using following 2 flag settings:

1. `-Ofast -m32 -march=native`
2. `-Ofast -m32 -march=native -fno-tree-vectorize`

The second setting just disable the vectorizer. However, when I checked the objdump of the 2 settings, both of them shows some packed instructions like `vmovapd`, `vxorpd`, etc.

Can anyone provide some explanations? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange gcc6.1 -O2 compiling behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549268/strange-gcc6-1-o2-compiling-behaviour)